# mysql distinct values without empty string and NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to retrieve mysql distinct values without empty string value and NULL value

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT CON.EMAILADDRESS AS 'E-MAIL'
FROM  STUDENT
INNER JOIN CONTACT CON ON STUDENT.CONTACT_ID = CON.ID
WHERE
(CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL 
OR  CON.EMAILADDRESS !=' ');
```

But in output still getting empty e-mails too. Can't figure out what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT CON.EMAILADDRESS AS 'E-MAIL'
FROM  STUDENT AST
INNER JOIN CONTACT CON ON AST.CONTACT_ID = CON.ID
WHERE length(trim(CON.EMAILADDRESS)) >0 and CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Your only problem is that you use OR instead of AND.

Let's look at the case where the value is NULL:

- `CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL` => FALSE
- `CON.EMAILADDRESS != ' '` => NULL

FALSE OR NULL => NULL. As the criteria doesn't result in TRUE you don't select NULLs.

And if the value is an empty string '', ' ', or whatever length:

- `CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL` => TRUE
- `CON.EMAILADDRESS != ' '` => FALSE

TRUE OR FALSE => TRUE. You select the empty string.

I suppose this is what confused you: in spite of having mistakenly used OR instead of AND you still removed some empty strings, but not all.

So:

```
WHERE CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL AND CON.EMAILADDRESS != ' ';
```

Or, as any string `!= ''` can't be NULL (`NULL != ''` => NULL, not TRUE), simply:

```
WHERE CON.EMAILADDRESS != '';
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND`

```
SELECT DISTINCT CON.EMAILADDRESS AS 'E-MAIL'
FROM STUDENT AST
INNER JOIN CONTACT CON ON AST.CONTACT_ID = CON.ID
WHERE CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL  
AND CON.EMAILADDRESS !=' '
AND CON.EMAILADDRESS !='';
```

Comment: It doesnt work if `CON.EMAILADDRESS` contains 2 or more blanks.

Comment: This worked. Maybe a silly question. will you please explain why 
(CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL 
OR  CON.EMAILADDRESS !=' ') did not work for me. I am considering both possibilities, get data where (not null or not empty), 

for (CON.EMAILADDRESS IS NOT NULL 
AND  CON.EMAILADDRESS !=' ')
isn't both conditions inside the brackets needs to be matched.

Comment: @T_g `''`is not that same as `' '`. You have at least on record in your DB where the EMAILADDRESS is filled with one blank.

Comment: When strings get compared trailing spaces do not matter. So `' '` *is* essentially the same as `'  '`.