# In this query, what do I need to add so it never displays blanks or null values?

Tags: javascript, java, sql

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT " +
          "COUNT(DISTINCT pd.id) FILTER (WHERE c.year NOT IN ('2020', '2021', '')) AS \"notCurrent\",  " +
```

This query is for a filter called notCurrent. The problem is, when the filter is selected, it still shows blank values, even though I added '' in the query. What do I need to do so no blanks/null values display when this filter is selected?

UI:

```js
export function forceFilter(key, filterVal, table, dataType, title) {
  var newTable = JSON.stringify(table);
  newTable = JSON.parse(newTable);
  var updated = false;
  if (key != "disclosure" && filterVal == "Unknown") {
    filterVal = "";
  } else if (filterVal == "Not Current") {
    filterVal = "notCurrent";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default empty "value" may not be an empty string, but `null`, you may want to try adding this to your `WHERE` clause

```
AND c.year IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check length greater than 0 after trimming that column and also check is not null.

Similar as below used sometime back
SELECT
DISTINCT email_id
FROM  FCSR_USER_MST
WHERE length(trim(email_id)) >0 and email_id IS NOT NULL

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169612/mysql-distinct-values-without-empty-string-and-null.)It would be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT pd.id) FILTER
    notCurrent = (IIF(c.year != '',ISNULL(c.year,'1900'),'1900'))
FROM yourtable pd
```

so, when it's empty or it's null it also returns the value 1900.